# strset function in <string.h>, C

Tags: c, string.h

When I learned C language, I heard strset function in C.

However, I cannot find it in the recent version of C.

Had it been deleted? If it was deleted, why is it deleted?

Comment: JFGI + RTFM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235359.aspx

Comment: It never existed. Except, *maybe* as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

strset is still exists.
VS 2017 - _strset_s

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char text[] = "Test Code";
    _strset_s(text, sizeof(text), '*');
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

Result
: *********

"Text Code" is total of 9 characters.
So output nine *('*')

> _strset_s(char *_Destination, size_t_DestinationSize, int _Value)